# Tyepscript send zip file in xhr POST request

Tags: node.js, typescript, multipartform-data

I am very new to typescript and have been trying to send zip file as multipart/form-data

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('templateFile', "sample.zip");
    var method='post';
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/scan', true);
    if (method === 'post' && formData) {
        //xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary="' + boundary + '"');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('user-agent','AzurePipeline/1.0.0');
        xhr.send(formData);

      } else {
        xhr.send();
      }
```

But I am getting the error:

```
buffer.js:713
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "string" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or ArrayBuffer. Received an instance of FormData
    at Function.byteLength (buffer.js:713:11)
    at exports.XMLHttpRequest.send (/Users/ngarg/code/tests/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:363:80)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/Users/ngarg/code/tests/multipart.js:41:13)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:323:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

My typescript version is : 
Version 3.7.3

I saw couple of examples online and most of them are doing the way I am doing, but still it always give this error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Form-data didn't work for me. I made the multi-part request instead and then for the successful result.